Referencing WinForms Class Library from .NET 8 and .NET Framework 4.8
I'm trying to create a class library that contains WinForms (UI screens) that could be shared between multiple projects. Problem is that some projects are using .NET 8 and some are still using .NET Framework 4.8
Is it actually possible? I tried using multi-targeting, but can't make it work.
After I added <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-windows;net48</TargetFrameworks> I got this error:

Assets file 'C:\Users...\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net48'.
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net48' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

Using netstandard doesn't seem possible for WinForms class library either. Has anyone done it successfully?
The only way I could do it so far was by creating two identical projects, one for .NET 8 and one for .NET Framework and copy-paste the forms from one to another after any change.

And what when someone wants to use your net8 lib on Linux? copy-paste the forms from one to another after any change - you can use software to do this btw

@flackoverstow Since WinForms is explicitly not Linux-Compatible that is highly improbable. I mean that fact is widely known.

Good question, but I will probably worry about it later. This is for a library used between internal projects, which are all on Windows. We are slowly upgrading them to .Net Core and need a way to share UI controls until everything is upgraded (may take years)

Exactly my point..

"Ensure that restore has run ...." - did you? I mean did you give up right away or did you attempt to solve the issues?

@flackoverstow you can use software to do this btw - do you mean like post-build events? This is actually a good idea! Would still look a bit ugly due to duplication, but might be an option. Or did you have something better in mind?

I am not 100% sure, but I think it should be possible to also share the same source file between two projects.

If you're moving to netcore, perhaps you should be moving away from WinForms

Or some synchronising software, a diff tool etc.. I've often wondered (never tried) if it's possible to have a netcore csproj and a framework csproj side by side sharing the same form files

"perhaps you should be moving away from WinForms" - totgesagte leben laenger. I don't think that's OP's choice to make. They are expecting the transition from Framework to Core to take years. What do you think such a proposal would set off at the company?

You can definitely multi-target a Winforms project to .NET 8 and .NET 4.8. We have many such projects (as we transition from 4.8 to 8+). If you change the targets you will have to unload and reload the project to avoid weird errors - did you try that? Also I'd recommend making a simple test project with a basic form to play around with first.

However when referencing we reference the DLL rather than the project using a reference like: <HintPath>..\..\..\..\<PATH TO PROJECT>\bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\<NAME OF ASSEMBLY>.dll</HintPath> (actual file names elided)

The $(Configuration) will be debug or release and the $(TargetFramework) will be the target framework being referenced. It does all get rather fiddly... We also ended up with  specific references inside ItemGroups for specific framewords, like <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48' "> in some weird edge cases, but generally you should be able to use NuGet packages where needed, and they handle referencing the correct versions of things.

This might be of use: https://www.cafe-encounter.net/p2312/multi-targetting-net-framework-and-net-core-in-a-single-project

@MatthewWatson oh my... THANK YOU! I spent a few hours googling the errors and trying different things, but didn't realize you just need to unload/reload the project. It seems working now!

@Fildor Winforms is not linux compatible, but there is a .NET 8 profile for Windows that does include Winforms

What does one gain by taking X years to port over WinForms core, that offsets the notion that you're then stuck with a less well developed dev experience and you're X years behind on moving off WinForms? I do nearly all my internal stuff in Blazor server now, and it's brilliant..

@JoelCoehoorn I don't understand. We still agree, there is no WinForms on Linux and it is not planned, right?
